# Assigning the Selected value from a DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

I have an MVC 3 application with the following view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TRP_MVC_Prototype.Models.usp_TM_Select_ShortName_PIDResult> 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<div id="main" style="background-color:White">
    <h1 style="background-color:transparent;color:Blue;">You are logged on as: @ViewBag.Message 

          @Html.DropDownList("shrt_ttl", new SelectList(Model,"short_title","short_title"))    
          @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Details", new { Shrt_title = "" })

    <a style="color:Blue;position:absolute; right:600px" @Html.ActionLink("Create Program Summary", "Index", "User_Guide")  </a>
    <a style="color:Blue;position:absolute; right:350px" @Html.ActionLink("Edit Program Summary", "Index", "User_Guide")  </a>
    <a style="color:Blue;position:absolute; right:150px" @Html.ActionLink("Delete TRP", "Index", "User_Guide")  </a>
    </h1>
    <h1 style="background-color:transparent;color:Blue;">Select TRP to View</h1>
    <h1 style="color:Gray";>______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________</h1>
</div>
```

I need to assign the Shrt_title string the return value from the selected value from the DropDownList. It seems to me that the assignment of Shrt_title is what needs to take place but I can't the correct variable to assign to that string. It gets returned to the controller but what to put in the variable is my question I think.
TIA
Bruce

Comment: It's not clear to what value you want to assign the default item of the dropdown list. Your model is an `IEnumerable<T>`. There is no information in it about the default value. So this is not a suitable view model to bind to a dropdownlist.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I am not clear (after research) how to do this. My model is a stored procedure from the controller returned as a ToList(). Sorry, TIA.